# Search for file and change for another

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need help, I made this code, it looks for a file "filename.txt and if it finds copy by another" filemame2.txt, but I want it to ask me in which drive c: \ or d: \ I want to search and change the file you found. can you help me?

```
@echo off
echo search...
if exist "filename.txt" (
echo file filename.txt found.
xcopy c:\filename.txt /y filename2.txt
) else (
echo file filemame.txt does not found.
)
echo finished.
echo press any key to exit...
pause >nul
```

Comment: For input use either `set /p "input=prompt text"` or `choice.exe /?` which returns an errorlevel.

Comment: [Windows cmd is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There's no such things like blocks of code `()` like that in DOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many different methods to do this using both `choice` or `set /p`

One way is to simply use goto, based on the errorlevel set by `choice` in the instance of choice, we simply use the letters `C` and `D` and no enter is required, one you press `C` or `D` on the keyboard, it will action the choice command.

```
@echo off
echo select the drive where the file should exist..
choice /C CD
if %errorlevel%==2 call goto :ddrive
if %errorlevel%==1 call goto :cdrive
:cdrive
if exist "c:\filename.txt" (xcopy /y "c:\filename.txt" /y "c:\filename2.txt") else (echo C:\filename.txt does not exist)
goto :EOF
:ddrive
if exist "d:\filename.txt" (xcopy /y "d:\filename.txt" "d:\filename2.txt") else (echo D:\filename.txt does not exist)
echo finished.
pause
```

Seeing as you only have 2 options, the second if can be eliminated, but I left it in, because you might want to add more drives.

For help on each of these, open `cmd.exe` and ru `choice /?`, `set /?` and for good measure, `if /?`

Based on your comment, If you want to include the full path in your prompt, meaning at the prompt, you have to type the drive letter and path to where you think the file exists. i.e `c:\some dir`:

```
@echo off
set /p "source=Please enter path to search file :"
set /p "dest=Please enter path to copy file to :" 
if exist "%source%\filename.txt" (xcopy /y "%source%\filename.txt" /y "%dest%\filename2.txt") else (echo C:\filename.txt does not exist)
echo finished.
pause
```

if you want to search for the file, you would need to use `dir /a-d /b /s filename.txt` and set it as a variable.

Comment: Ok, I changed something and it worked. but I wanted it not to be limited to c: \ filename.txt, but look for all folders on the c: \ drive.

I still wanted to add the option of a folder type h: \ folder \ 1

Comment: Do you want to recursively search for a file within a drive when given, or actually type the full path to where the file exists?

Comment: I want to search for a file "filename.txt" inside a drive when supplied, option c: \ and have the option to be able to enter a full path where the file filename.txt may exist.